# Are "how to create this synth sound" questions welcome?

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of synth players and electronic musicians out there, and they all want to sound as good as their favourite records. I can very well imagine people (including myself) flooding this site with questions like

- [How to create a Acid Synth Stab sound?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/20756/how-to-create-a-acid-synth-stab-sound)
- [Brutal synth drop](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/20559/brutal-synth-drop)
- [Simple supersaw lead](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/20765/simple-supersaw-lead)

I can also imagine synth-specific questions, such as "how to create the Man in the Mirror bells on a Roland JUNO-G?" I would definitely post them non synth-specificly, but others may not.

So my question is

- Are these on-topic?
- Are these welcome?

A related issue may be hardware vs. software synth questions, given that seemingly the majority of this community is software-based.

Comment: Incidentally, keep an eye on [this meta discussion](http://meta.sound.stackexchange.com/questions/58/new-tag-request-sound-a-like), as the eventual outcome will likely determine at least one of the appropriate tags for such questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot imagine why not. If someone is searching "how to create a Acid Synth Stab sound", **I sure would like them to find *this* site.**

If it turns out that these questions are somehow over-running the site in a bad way, *then* we can have a look at the issue. But having too many questions is a high-quality problem, and we shouldn't create a bunch of rules precluding this content before a problem actually exists.

**Remember that search is the lifeblood of this site.** If this is the type of question your potential audience is searching for, they should be asked and answered here. Once you're past  alllll those basic questions that have been asked hundreds of times on every other site on this subject, it's these specific, long-tailed questions that only a few people can answer — and ***do*** answer — that will really make this site shine.

This site should strive to become The Complete Compendium™ of all things in sound design.

Comment: These questions grow irritating, and have for much time.  Questions about how to design something for ideas, great, those are fine.  Questions of "how do I make this exact sound?" With a clip.  No, these are irritating.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [what Robert said](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/a/45/6387), this is not only encouraged - it's supported by code. [Links to Sound Cloud and YouTube are treated in a special way here](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled) - a miniature player is displayed in their place so that you can hear the clip without opening any additional pages. The link goes to the video production site, but the information is the same.

This means, if folks want to go as far as to give *near* examples of what they're trying to produce and then explain what they hope to be different, you end up with a *very* interesting question that allows a searcher to just hit a play button to see if it relates to what they're trying to accomplish.

Sound in general is extremely difficult to articulate in words, but I'll agree that it's entirely possible to make these types of questions clear, easily discovered and helpful to others.